# Getting a list of VALUES rather than CLASSES in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This problem seems very simple, but I'm having trouble finding an already existing solution on StackOverflow.

When I run a sqlalchemy command like the following

```
valid_columns = db.session.query(CrmLabels).filter_by(user_id=client_id).first()
```

I get back a CrmLabels object that is not iterable. If I print this object, I get a list

```
[Convert Source, Convert Medium, Landing Page]
```

But this is not iterable. I would like to get exactly what I've shown above, except as a list of strings

```
['Convert Source', 'Convert Medium', 'Landing Page']
```

How can I run a query that will return this result?

Comment: I would not suggest this, but you can use `eval` but it should be avoided. Other than that I can not think of any other way.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the source of the `CrmLabels` class.

Comment: Probably you just want something like `session.query(CrmLabels.name)`

Comment: Please do not use `eval`. If you want to query the whole table, but as result tuples instead of mapped objects, use `query(CrmLabels.__table__)`. But I think this seems a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks all. I ended up grabbing each value out of the table by using the class properties (example CrmLabels.status). It's not ideal, but it works and that's all I really need at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below change should do it:**

```
valid_columns = (
    db.session.query(CrmLabels).filter_by(user_id=client_id)
    .statement.execute()  # just add this
    .first()
)
```

However, you need to be certain about the order of columns, and you can use `valid_columns.keys()` to make sure the values are in the expected order.

*Alternatively, you can create a dictionary using `dict(valid_columns.items())`.*